# Updating Foreign Keys in a Master Detail Relationship on a Junction Object

Tags: master-detail, custom, automation, junction-object

I've created a custom object called CampaignQuote that has a master-detail relationship with Campaigns and Quotes/Orders. In this use case Quotes/Orders are used in the same way opportunities would be used. I am trying to pull information from the quote and on the Campaign create a roll-up summary for all CampaignQuote objects related to the campaign.

The issue now is that I am trying to automate the creation/update of a CampaignQuote record. The user must enter a contact on the quote via a lookup field. I want this to fire a workflow, process builder or visualflow that will insert the quote id that was just created and look to see if the inserted contact has a campaign it is related to and insert its id as the master-detail on CampaignQuote.

Trying to do this through automation I have found that I cannot easily assign variables to the master-detail fields (Campaign and Quote) and insert them into the record. Does anyone have any recommendations for how I can pass this information onto the CampaignQuote when a quote is created/updated or any examples of junction objects that might help me?

Thank you